# Insert incremental time between two rows determined by column entry

Tags: r, time, row, data.table

Sorry me again. I will keep on trying but I want help in case I can't figure out within the next hour.

My data looks like this:

```
B<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),EVID=c(1,1,1,0,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1),VALUE=seq(15))
B$TIME<-c(Sys.time()+6*3600*(seq_len(nrow(B))-1))
```

Actually the time is more variable, and each ID may have multiple EVID of 2.

I wanted to add one hour increments between the times for EVID=2 for as many hours as they are apart, i.e., for each pair of EVID=2, I add one hour until the time is within one hour to the second EVID=2 in the pair, so I can get something like this:
(value and ID are just duplicate previous rows)

```
   ID EVID VALUE                TIME
1   1    1     1 2013-05-31 07:51:09
2   1    1     2 2013-05-31 13:51:09
3   1    1     3 2013-05-31 19:51:09
4   1    0     4 2013-06-01 01:51:09
5   1    1     5 2013-06-01 07:51:09
6   1    2     6 2013-06-01 13:51:09
6   1    2     6 2013-06-01 14:51:09
6   1    2     6 2013-06-01 15:51:09
6   1    2     6 2013-06-01 16:51:09
6   1    2     6 2013-06-01 17:51:09
6   1    2     6 2013-06-01 18:51:09
7   1    2     7 2013-06-01 19:51:09
8   1    1     8 2013-06-02 01:51:09
9   2    1     9 2013-06-02 07:51:09
10  2    1    10 2013-06-02 13:51:09
11  2    2    11 2013-06-02 19:51:09
11  2    2    11 2013-06-02 20:51:09
11  2    2    11 2013-06-02 21:51:09
11  2    2    11 2013-06-02 22:51:09
11  2    2    11 2013-06-02 23:51:09
11  2    2    11 2013-06-02 0:51:09
12  2    2    12 2013-06-03 01:51:09
13  2    1    13 2013-06-03 07:51:09
14  2    1    14 2013-06-03 13:51:09
15  2    1    15 2013-06-03 19:51:09
```

Below is my brainstorm/attempt:

```
library(data.table)
BDT <- data.table(row=1:nrow(B), B, key="ID")
BDT[,list(row,EVID,c(EVID)==2)]

attach(B)

newB<-BDT[c(EVID)==2,list(row=row+1,ID=ID,EVID=EVID,VALUE=VALUE,TIME=head(TIME+3600,-1))]
finalB<-rbind(BDT,newB)[order(EVID,decreasing=TRUE)][order(row)][,-1,with=FALSE]
```

However, this adds one row of Time+1 hour to each EVID=2 which is not what I desired.

The next thing I tried duplicates every row after the first which is not what I wanted, but has the advantage of sparing my from typing out all the names of the columns (I have about 32)

```
newB<-B[c(1,rep(2:nrow(B),each=2)),] 
## My wild guess -- as.numeric(head(TIME))-as.numeric(tail(TIME)))/3600 doesn't work. I know it says that from row 2 to last row, repeat each row twice
newB[c(FALSE,TRUE),"EVID"]<-2
newB[c(FALSE,TRUE),"TIME"]<-newB[c(FALSE,TRUE),"TIME"]+3600
```

Thank you for any feedback.

=================================================================

eddie's code works well with my example, which I thought was a good representation but my actual data keep getting

> error in seq.int(...) wrong sign in 'by' argument

(...) varies depending on what I was trying

I have a relatively large data, the column that I use as the ID as in the example is in the middle of the data table; I see even from my small sample data if I place the ID along with the other names in the list, R will recognize item 2 as having n+1 columns than item 1 in the rbind. But if I don't include it in the list so that I may use the by=ID, R complains that names are in different order. If a do not list one of the unimportant columns in the beginning of the data, R says item 2 has n-1 columns compared to item 1!

I thought that perhaps my error comes from my time being not exactly hours apart, but by test runs I see that small differences are tolerated, and rounding, either to hour or doing integers, doesn't help.

I tried using length.out, ignoring the warning

> Warning message: In .rbind.data.table(...) :   Argument 2 has names in
>   a different order. Columns will be bound by name for consistency with
>   base. Alternatively, you can drop names (by using an unnamed list) and
>   the columns will then be joined by position. Or, set use.names=FALSE.

But then the code does not add to between the 2's except at the end, where it adds too many!

What am I doing wrong? I've been pulling all-nighter for this :(

OK so when I rearrange the original data I can get rid of the warnings. However, the insertions are still happening at the end of the data only and they were too many.

Comment: Maybe `?seq.Date` will help?

Comment: That does seem like what I wanted! My computer is running out of battery now, but I think I may be able to organize by time between start of first EVID=2 to end of second EVID=2 and then order by ID then by time--I just need to figure out how to recognize the EVID's!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(B)
dt[, TIME := as.POSIXct(TIME)]

rbind(dt, dt[EVID == 2,
             list(EVID=EVID[1],
                  VALUE=VALUE[1],
                  TIME=seq.POSIXt(TIME[1], TIME[2], "hour")),
             by = ID])[!duplicated(paste(ID,EVID,TIME))][order(ID, TIME)]
```

Comment: Worked wonderfully for my example, but I've been getting error messages for my actual data. I will figure that part out!

Comment: `Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument` What is the argument `by=ID` doing? Why do we use ID? and what would make it work?

Comment: I modified it a little to work with shorter intervals than 1 hour, which is why you were getting that error. The `by=ID` argument says "do this operation for/by each `ID`".

Comment: I created an INDEX column to replace of ID, which has multiple pairs of consecutive 2's. I also rounded up my TIME, which may be 1 minutes away from whole hours apart. Still debugging

Comment: I tried changing seq.POSIXct to seq.int, rounding my times to nearest whole hour, use length.out instead of by...